# When should I stop the recursive `get_peers` DHT search?

Tags: bittorrent, dht

Since DHT nodes might be malicious and report fake `values` (i.e. fake peers) we should not stop searching for peers as soon as we get any response, in hope of getting real peers from another good node.

We don't even have to assume malicious intentions: we might get more (or even better) peers when exploring a different branch of the DHT that we might've missed if we just focus on the shortest branch.

When should I stop the recursive `get_peers` DHT search? Should we just keep searching until all nodes in the search space are exhausted? I.e. once we don't get any non-queried `nodes` from the last candidate.

Answer (score 0):

An iterative lookup for a *K*-closest-node-set is complete if

A) all of the following are true

1. there are no requests in flight (i.e. got responses, ICMP errors or timeouts) whose responses could alter the set of closest nodes
2. your closest-set has at least *K* entries
3. there are no closer candidates retrieved from `nodes`/`nodes6` fields than the K-furthest entry in result set

or

B) when you run out of candidates to query

When calculating the K-closest-set you also need to account for eligibility for for the followup operation (if any). E.g. if you want to follow up with a `announce_peer` then the K-closest-node-set must consist of nodes that returned a `token` since not returning a token implies [inability to store additional values](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0033.html#changed-announce-accounting).